# How to know when to use preposition with an adverb of place?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs

I saw a video of an English tutor saying that we say:

- *I am going home*, not
- *I am going to home*.

because *home* is an adverb here. Why do we not follow the same guidance with sentences like:

- *I am feeling at home*?

Wouldn't it be correct to say:

- *I am feeling home*?

This also applies to other examples like:

- *I got my pen there*, and
- *I got my pen from there.*

How is the meaning between them different? Is there a rule of thumb for when we can use a preposition before an adverb?

Comment: First of all, there's no way of explaining what's going on whilst describing words like *home*, *here* and *there* as adverbs. They're intransitive prepositions.  The verb *go* takes a preposition phrase complement. That might be *to the shops* or *home* or *there* or *away* or *round the corner* or *into the night* or *down the road*. In *go home* there's already a preposition phrase and we don't need another. When *home* is a destination we don't need another prep. However, if it's a location, we need a prep like *at* before it.

Comment: Don't have time to give you all the info re *there*. Perhaps someone can write you an actual answer!

Comment: What's the difference between *there* and *from there*?  If you say: *I got this pizza there*, you actually went to the pizza parlor and picked it up. While if you say *I got this pizza from there*, possibly you just called them up and they delivered it.

Comment: @PeterShor Good question; _get_ means 'come to have' (a result) in both cases, but _there_ refers to a distal location as a source, leaving speculation open about what action is actually the cause, hence 'possibly'. Other interpretations are available for more specific scenarios.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Could you please spare some time to wrtie a complete answer? I looked all over the internet, I did not get any useful explanation. I also went through Wren and martin but it went in vain. If could write a complete answer I believe it would help the wider audience as well or please suggest some book wherein I can find answer to this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible ambiguities when using "home" as an adverb? (study home, write home...)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/228324/possible-ambiguities-when-using-home-as-an-adverb-study-home-write-home)